# RAD tool for Javascript framework like Dojo?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dojo

i would like to create a web application using DOJO. I'm an Asp.Net developer, but, about javascript framework, i really like Dojo instead the Ajax Control Toolkit by Microsoft. 
So i'm asking you if exists some Visual RAD Ide for (for example) Dojo, or maybe, how can i integrate / write Asp.Net database driven apps with Dojo ? 
Is it possible and... simple ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wavemaker](https://www.wavemaker.com) is an IDE that uses dojo on the front end, along with ajax and java or else amazon cloud hosting on the backend: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavemaker
http://www.wavemaker.com/

Qooxdoo is an alternative to dojo that is more desktop-like and had some designers, but I don't know how up to date they are: 
http://qooxdoo.org/
and designers: 
http://qxtransformer.org/
http://qooxdoo-contrib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/qooxdoo-contrib/trunk/qooxdoo-contrib/qooxit/

QT Designer is a great visual designer for desktop applications, and this tool can convert the files to javascript: http://code.google.com/p/jsqt/

For mobile development, there is Ext Designer but it costs money:
http://www.sencha.com/products/designer/

The most visual studio-like option out there that works in the browser is some framework from china I think called jslinb, it uses its own javascript framework: 
http://www.linb.net/
See this demo of their IDE for example:
http://www.linb.net/VisualJS/UIBuilder.html

And if you go with YUI instead of dojo, one IDE-like demo is WireIt:
http://neyric.github.com/wireit/

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...  Yes , there is nsBasic-Apps (for webPages and mobile devices) .
code in nsBasic  transform code into javascript .
But it is only for WebKit browsers ...Vernon